# Empty cells when using an apply function

Tags: pandas, apply

So I am trying to calculate a value from one column or another based based on which one has data available into a new column. This is the code I have right now. It doesn't seem to notice when there is no data present and always goes to the "else" statement. My dataframe is an imported excel file. Thanks for any advice!

```
def create_sulfide_col(row):
   if row["Sulphate-S(HCL Leachable)_%S"] is None:
       val = row["Total-S_%S"] - row["Sulphate-S(HCL Leachable)_%S"]
   else:
       val = ["Total-S_%S"]- df["Sulphate-S_%S"]

   return val

df["Sulphide-S(calc)-C_%S"] = df.apply(lambda row: create_sulfide_col(row), axis='columns')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is can be done by using numpy.where

Import numpy as np

```
df['newcol'] = np.where(df["Sulphate-S(HCL Leachable)_%S"].isna(),df["Total-S_%S"]- df["Sulphate-S(HCL Leachable)_%S"],df["Total-S_%S"]- df["Sulphate-S_%S"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! In this case would you know how to address the following error: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!.

Comment: I have edited my answer i had a typo try now if this didn't work try to replace .isna() with ==''

Comment: Thank you! I got it working now, much appreciated!